# Merge multiple checkbox value in one list in a GET url

Tags: django, get, checkbox

In our web application (django based, with solr backend) we have some checkboxes with multiple choices allowed. Problem is my url is getting longer (we're using GET method)

Something like

```
?what=&where=&within=any&rooms=any&rooms=any&baths=any&baths=any&sqrft=&sqrft=&price=&price=&property-type=any&date=any
```

is it possible to merge the repeated ones in one list comma separated?

```
?what=&where=&within=any&rooms=any,any&baths=any,any&sqrft=any,any&price=any,any&type=any&date=any
```

they are all ranges [min,max] so it would be good (i guess) to keep them grouped togheter.

thanks in advance

Comment: And why do you care how your URLs with a lot of get parameters look like? I think you can prepare get string with JS and then do some extra work processing it on server side, but what's the profit?

Comment: my boss cares more than me, actually. i don't have a real interest in it, but i started googling around a bit and couldn't find anything about...

Comment: If you really have urls with doubled names of parameters like this: `&rooms=any&rooms=any` than something is off with your markup. Care to provide a working link ?

Comment: we have a private staging machine, so cannot give you any working link.. no it's not a markup problem, user are querying via ranged values with multiple select boxes or checkboxes. i gave them the same name so i can use request.GET.getlist("rooms") to fetch all the values. it's normal behaviour for multiple selections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things you can do:

1) Prepare the shorthand querystring using Javascript and then parse it on the server

2) When the user submits a URL with a long querystring, redirect them to a URL with a short querystring

3) Do a combination of 1 and 2. If the user has Javascript enabled, do 1, otherwise do 2